# Can I have android on the phone but Ubuntu on the computer when it is plugged in?

Tags: dual-boot, android, ubuntu-for-android

Is it possible to have the Android OS on your phone but when it is plugged into a computer the computer will run Ubuntu? Also, does it support OS X?

Comment: Could you clarify? Why would the OS running on your phone affect the OS running on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Currently - not. There were plans to do so, but Canonical is still waiting for a partner to realize that project. You can see its site: http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about mounting/syncing your phone - your question isn't entirely clear

Your android phone will likely play nice with your linux system assuming you are using [libmtp](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/) and its a supported phone. Chances are it should work. If you have a CM based rom, you also have the option of mounting your phone as mass storage, which is compatible with nearly anything.

If you're using ios you need [libimobiledevice](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone)

The worst case scenario is your system can't mount the device. You won't magically be forced into running windows or OS X!